# How to calculate the sum of int32 and int8

Tags: go

How to calculate the sum of int32 and int8 in Go?

````
func main() {
    var u32 uint32
    u32 = 434
    
    var i int8
    i = -1
    
    fmt.Println(u32 + i) // expect the result is 433
}```

compile error: invalid operation: u32 + i (mismatched types uint32 and int8)
````

Comment: Convert them to the same type. This is basic stuff. Please start with [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1), specifically the part about [type conversions](https://tour.golang.org/basics/13).

Comment: Your title does not match the code in the question. Is it `uint32` or `int32`? Without knowing the specifics of these variables, the only sure way would be to convert both to `int64`, i.e. `int64(u32) + int64(i)`. If `u32` can fit into `int32` and the sum is expected to be smaller than max `int32` value, use `int32` (even better, declare the `u32` variable as signed).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert integer types using [type conversion](https://tour.golang.org/basics/13) into each other. Note that converting a "larger" type into a "smaller" one can lead to an overflow resulting in a completely different number. (It will not throw an error, so you might not notice immediately.)

In this example I am converting both to int (which is int64 if you are on a 64bit system, and int32 if you are on a 32bit system), because I can't convert an `int8` into an `uint32` as it wouldn't support negative numbers and I can't convert an `uint32` into an `int8` as it couldn't hold the big numbers.

```golang
func main() {
    var (
        u32 uint32 = 434
        i8  int8   = -1
    )

    fmt.Println(int(u32) - int(i8))
}
```

Note: If there is no specific reason to do otherwise, just use `int` everywhere. A specific reason could be that your a creating an interface to some hardware that works with more specific types, or you are writing software for hardware with limited cache. Or maybe you have something you really need to squeeze every byte out of. Otherwise you will make your live just a lot harder for no reason.